# MenuItem enable style not working in contextmenu

Tags: wpf, xaml, menu, styles, contextmenu

I'm using the `ExpressionDark` theme for my WPF app, it has a custom style for `MenuItems`.
When a `MenuItem` is disabled it should use a gray style to reflect this, and it works for `MenuItems` inside the `Menu` control:

[image: Working menu state]

It does however not work for `MenuItems` that are in a `ContextMenu` (Copy is disabled)

[image: Copy should look like disabled]

I have tracked down the problem to the TextBlock style, if I remove this style it works for the ContextMenu, but other styles break with it removed

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBrush}" />
</Style>
```

**EDIT:** It doesn't matter if I use a `MenuItem` or my custom `GestureMenuItem`, but what do matter is if i use a _ char or not (For key shortcuts) If I remove _ then the style wont work in `MainMenu` either.

The relevant style for the `MenuItem`:

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
</Trigger>
```

Source code found [here](https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/AvalonDock/FreePIE.GUI/Themes/ExpressionDark.xaml#L1932). The relevant `ContextMenu` XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Text"
    Height="Auto"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    AcceptsReturn="True"
    IsReadOnly="true">
    <TextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="Copy">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource IconCopy}"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <Separator></Separator>
            <MenuItem cal:Message.Attach="Clear()" Header="Clear All">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource IconDelete}"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
```

`MenuItems` in working main menu (`GestureMenuItem` inherits `MenuItem` and uses same style):

```
<Menu IsMainMenu="True">
    <Menu.Resources>
        <Image x:Key="ViewIcon" x:Shared="false"
            Source="{Binding Path=Icon}" />
    </Menu.Resources>
    <!-- Items here removed to shorten XAML -->
    <MenuItem Header="_Script">
        <common:GestureMenuItem x:Name="RunScript" Header="_Run script" Key="F5">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="{StaticResource IconPlay}"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </common:GestureMenuItem>
      <common:GestureMenuItem x:Name="StopScript" Header="_Stop script" Key="F5" Modifiers="Shift">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="{StaticResource IconStop}"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </common:GestureMenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
    <!-- Items here removed to shorten XAML -->
</Menu>
```

Gesture item style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Caliburn:GestureMenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
</Style>
```

**I came up with a work around, it wont give the exact same style, but it works, should I go for it?**

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
</Trigger>
```

Both gesture text and icon is gray with this solution so maybe it a actually a better solution than just setting Forecolor to gray:

[image: Opacity solution]

Comment: How are the context menu items defined? It might be that you just need to create a second style that targets the right type.

Comment: How are the menu items in the main menu defined? You are using the `Header` property to display the text rather than a `TextBox`. This will be why the code doesn't work.

Comment: Please see edit, there is no difference in how the menu items are defined

Comment: There is. The main menu uses `common:GestureMenuItem` while the context menu uses `MenuItem`. These are different. How does the former display the text?

Comment: They uses the exact same style, let me fire up my WMWare and test but I'm pretty sure GestureItems wotn work either in contexct menu

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that GestureItems would work in the context menu, just that it defined how the menu was displayed differently.

Comment: If i remove the _ char from the MainMenu item the disable style wont work in MainMenu either... What? :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by replacing the Forecolor property setter with a Opacity property setter, this will also effect gesture text and icon which is also the default style's way of doing it

[image: Opacity solution]

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.3"/>
</Trigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found targeting the ContentPresenters for the InputGestureText and Header individually is more efficient. Targeting the whole MenuItem in my case resulted in see-through MenuItems. I have shown how you can get around that below:

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
    <Setter TargetName="HeaderHost" Property="Opacity" Value="0.3"/>
    <Setter TargetName="IGTHost" Property="Opacity" Value="0.3"/>
</Trigger>
```